# Bot Composer - Join list from Luis entity

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, bot-framework-composer

*Bot Framework Composer v1.4.1*

I have a bot connected to Luis, which returns a list entity that I need to operate with that data.
The entity that I get is a list of categories, and I need to concatenate all the elements of that list into a string

```
"entities": {
  "CategoryList": [
    [
      "sub-13-Imprimante",
      "12-materiels"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The expected result is

```
"sub-13-Imprimante,12-materiels"
```

I have tried different options but none concatenate the result as expected.

```
@CategoryList //This only assign first element of the array ("sub-13-Imprimante")

join(@CategoryList, ',') //Throw error
```

The error obtained in the join statement is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'NewTicket.fr-fr.lg:@CategoryList evaluates to sub-13-Imprimante which is not a list. [SendActivity_D8EXfc]  Error occurred when evaluating '- ${join(@CategoryList, ',')}'.
```

It would seem that when calling @CategoryList, it already returns the first item, instead of the entire list.

How could I do to obtain all the values of the array concatenated in a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@CategoryList` will return the first and only the first value found for the entity. `@@CategoryList` will return the entire thing. So, what you need is `join(@@CategoryList, ',')`

See more info here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-memory?tabs=v2x#memory-shorthand-notations

Comment: For clarification, @@CategoryList returns the entire entity in text format, including the square brackets and quotation marks. To generate an array, you must first clean the excess characters `[\r\n  [\r\n    \"sub-13-Imprimante\",\r\n    \"12-materiels\"\r\n  ]\r\n]`

Comment: For .NET; correct. Seems to be a bug/partiy issue between the two SDKs. I have filed a bug on it here: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/6327